# What are the main requirements of processing for beef to be kosher?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, meat

I’m interested mainly in the most likely differences between kosher and non-kosher beef that one who eats non-kosher beef regularly would be likely to notice if they switched to eating kosher beef. For example the whole thing of koshering… like with salt etc which I gather isn’t typically done for non-kosher meat?

Comment: Clarification: your question title makes it seem like processing is what makes the beef kosher, but then you specify that you're asking about what will be noticeable if one switches to kosher. Consider editing the title , especially because processing isn't the only thing that determines kashrut. For example, the health of the animal prior to slaughter also plays a major role.

Comment: I have heard that kosher meat is saltier, but I cannot attest to it personally.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: This might help: https://www.kosher.com/jewish-learning/kosher-meat-poultry-and-fish and https://www.myjewishlearning.com/article/kosher-meat/